# Do infinite tests guarantee an outcome if the probability is decreasing

Tags: probability

Say you look at the first two digits of pi, then the next three then the next four is it guaranteed that one of the sets of digits will be made up of the same digits?

Assuming all digits are random the first two have a probability of being the same of 0.1, the next three 0.01 and so on making the probability of it occuring approach 0.11111...

Does this mean that there is a 1 in 9 chance of this occuring? Or do the infinite tests somehow 'win' and almost guarantee that it happens?

Comment: Note that we must assume that the digits of $\pi$ behave like a pseudorandom digit generator. Then, you can actually bound the probability by the sum you mentioned, so the probability is at most $\frac{1}{9}$. Since the first several trials fail , this probability decreases even more drastically. So, it is not only not guaranteed , but very unlikely that such a number will occur.

Comment: With a similar argument , we can virtually rule out that the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ form a palindrome for some integer $n>3$.

Comment: When you say "Does this mean there is a 1 in 9 chance of this occuring" what does "this" refer to?  Can the question be clarified?

Comment: @Michael The event that eventually a number with equal digits will occur is meant.

Comment: What is a "number with equal digits"? Is the number 2 such a number?

Comment: @Michael The text in the question describes which digits we look at , we begin with $2$ digits hence your special case does not apply.

Comment: So to clarify the question is essentially a way of asking if the probabilities of infinite trials don't approach 1, but there are infinite trials, can we say that the chance of it ever happening is the probability it approaches or does the fact that there are infinite trials guarantee that it happens eventually.

Comment: If you divide the digits into consecutive disjoint blocks of size 2, 3, 4, and so on, and each trial is for one block, then Peter interpreted your question correctly in his first comment: If $A_i$ is the event that trial $i$ is a success then the union bound ensures $P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i]\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P[A_i]$ (infinity does not “win”). However your question seems to be about $\pi$, and we know the first few digits of $\pi$ are 31415, so the first 2 trials surely fail and they have probability 0, rather than probability 1/10 and 1/100.

Comment: I also wonder if you are really asking about **asymptotic events**, such as if there are ever 1000 consecutive 1s (with no constraint on where it occurs) or if there are arbitrarily long run lengths of the same repeated digit, for which a conjectured asymptotic i.i.d. model of digits may be a reasonable approximation. For a sequence $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of i.i.d. equally likely digits in the set $\{0, 1, ..., 9\}$, the probability of getting a run length of $k$ consecutive 1s in a row is 1 (for any positive integer $k$). So in this case "infinity wins."